# MongoDB - Embeded Version for "Voting with Atomic Operators"

Tags: mongodb, atomic, voting

I read the [Voting with Atomic Operators](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/votes/) article. In this article, the `voters` field is an array of `ObjectId`s. But I would like to store the `voters` as an array of embedded documents with the following format:

```
{
  user: ObjectId,
  date: Date,
  isDownvote: Boolean,  // If false, it's an upvote.
}
```

The user can upvote or downvote the post just like the voting system provided by Stack Overflow. So, for example, when the user want to upvote a post, there are cases to consider:

- If a downvote by the user already exists, then update the vote's `isDownvote` to `false`.
- Else push a new vote with `isDownvote` being `false`.

How can I push/pull a vote in single query with this format of votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this fully atomically is:

```
db.posts.update({'_id':post_id}, {
    '$pull': {'votes.user':ObjectId},
    '$addToSet': {votes: {
        user: objectId,
        date: Date,
        isdownvote: isdownvote
    }}
})
```

As already said, there is no `upsert` for subdocuments so this kind of cheats and deletes the old vote and writes it again. The `date` field should still be ok because if the user votes again then the `date` field should change to the last time that user voted so in my mind that part makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the answer. The queries in the [Voting with Atomic Operators](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/votes/) article also update the counters, but I think there's no way to achieve this in a single query in this case.

Comment: @TrantorLiu Hmm, no that one does require two queries even in this case which sucks

Answer (score 1):

```
$push : { voters : {
  user: ObjectId,
  date: Date
}}
```

Comment: Sorry I had edit the question. I added a new field `isDownvote`.

Comment: Me too. There's no `upsert` for embedded documents. `$addToSet` only add the subdoc if not exists, but it doens't update the exists one.

Comment: I also came up with the similar findings :)